# Query objects by matching elements from a list using SpringData Mongo Repositories

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

My current setup looks like this: I have SpringData Mongo repositories and the following class structure:

User.class:

```
public class User {
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;

  @Id
  private String id;

  @DBRef
  private List<Division> divisions;

  [...]
}
```

and Division.class

```
public class Division {
  @Id
  private String id;

  [...]
}
```

I now want to gather all user's who are part of a certain division. How can I accomplish this using the SpringData Mongo Repositories?

For clarification, the programmatic (but very inefficient) approach would be

```
List<User> matchingUser = new ArrayList<>();
List<User> users = userRepository.findAll()
for(User user: users) {
  if(user.divisions.contains(matchingDivision)) {
    matchingUser.add(user);
  }
}
```

I already tried the following, but had no luck:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String> {
  @Query(value = "{'divisions': {$elemMatch: ?0 } }")
  public List<User> findAllByDivisionInDivisions(Division division);
}
```

My complete project can be found [here](https://www.github.com/steilerdev/myVerein), but if you need any specific information just let me know and I will provide them.

Answer (score 0):

Do your search based on the id, not the whole division, since it is a DBRef.  Otherwise you have to resolve every DBRef which is an extra fetch from the database.

```
@Query("{ 'divisions.$id' : ?0 }")
public List<User> findUserByDivisionId(String divisionId);
```